# Why don't Java logical operators && and || work with arrays?

Tags: java, binary, boolean, logic

I am effectively trying to write a multiple-bit if-statement in binary. If val is true, I would like to return the correct value of x. However, if val is false, I would like to return all values of the array to be false.
This is effectively the same as checking all values within the array against the value of val. Why doesn't this work?

```
boolean[] ifStatement(bit0, bit1, bit2, bit3, val) {
    boolean[] x = {bit0, bit1, bit2, bit3};
    return (x && val);
}
```

In response to comments asking what I mean by the question, the following is a representation using an 8-bit AND gate in the program Logisim:

[image: val is off, returns false]

[image: val is on, returns the original input value]

I am also aware that it is very easy to do the same thing using a for statement. My question is why is the example code not possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because a `boolean[]` is not a `boolean`...

Comment: Please review the acceptable operands for the operators you're asking about.

Comment: try `for(int i = 0; i < x.lenght(); i++) if(x[i] != val) return false; return true`

Comment: You can't ask "why *doesn't* it work" until you have at least a sketch of an argument why it *should* work.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik:  To be fair to the OP, that title was actually edited in.

Comment: The && operator should support multiple bits. Although I don't have a complete understanding of the Java compiler, I do understand that it is possible to implement the same argument using logic gates, as shown in my edited post. I therefore see no reason as to why it cannot be implemented in Java...

Comment: @Makoto It was just pulled out from his question: "Why doesn't this work?"

Comment: It could have been implemented as you describe, Fraser. It wasn't. There are alternatives; see David Given's answer for one.

Comment: *Implementation* is the least of your worries here. Have you asked yourself about the interaction of your proposed semantics with all the rest of the language features?

Comment: OK, thanks. Confused as to why something like this wouldn't be added, but I guess I have my answer anyway!

Comment: The original Java was really low level --- e.g. memory allocation only ever happened in the `new` operator! --- and they wouldn't have been able to implement something like this without silently emitting calls to run-time functions, which they wouldn't have wanted to do. Plus they had a philosophical objection to operator overloading (although the language has it in places...). Plenty of languages have these kind of features; as you point out they're useful and the syntax is unambiguous. Just, Java doesn't. Try Scala instead.

Comment: Thanks very much, cleared it up.

Comment: Your revision cleared something up.  Check the edit to my answer, and see if a `byte` as opposed to a `boolean[]` would make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. You have check each item. It'd be kind of nice if it did work, but there you have it.

There are, however, special classes like [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) that provide special functionality for big collections of booleans. You might find one of these useful. Typically not worth the effort for short numbers of booleans, though.

Answer (score 3):

An array is a type all its own, not a `boolean`.  So you can't use logical operators on an array type.

From your question description, it sounds like you just want to check every value in the array against some baseline boolean.  You can do that with a loop over all elements in the array, and if any of don't match up to the baseline, return false.

```
public boolean ifStatement(boolean base, boolean... values) {
    for(boolean value : values) {
        if(!(value && base)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**:  After your diagram explained a few things, it seems that a boolean array is the wrong data structure.  Why not work with a byte directly?  (8 bits = 1 byte)

```
public byte ifStatement(boolean val, byte value) {
    return val ? value : (byte) 0x00;
}
```

You're either returning value or nothing in your example, so I believe that this would work better.

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean[] x = {bit0, bit1, bit2, bit3};
return (x && val);
```

> Why doesn't this work?

Your proposed meaning of that expression matches the semantics of the standard *map* higher-order function in the FP paradigm. Interestingly enough, I am not aware of any actual FP language which would have its `AND` operator overloaded to mean `map((applyPartial(AND, val), coll)` when one of its operands is a collection.

But, constraining the discussion to Java, such a feature would be deeply incongruent with everything else in it. It would make a *logical* operator suddenly behave like a batch collection operator; there is *nothing* even remotely close to that in Java, which is meant to be as unsurprising to beginners as possible, and especially so to people already familiar with C.

BTW you should have at least picked `&` because `&&` has short-circuiting semantics, something which makes no sense in your proposal.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because the Java compiler doesn't interpret your wishes but adheres to its specification.

And the boolean operators only work with, well, booleans. Arrays of booleans aren't booleans.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need for loop / bitwise operators:

```
boolean []ifStatement(boolean b1, boolean b2, boolean b3, boolean b4, boolean val) {
    if (!val) {
        boolean []result = {false, false, false, false};
        return result;
    } else {
        boolean []result = {b1, b2, b3, b4};
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about doing it this way but unfortunately the point of my project is to use only boolean variables and the operators && and ||. Good answer though, thanks.

Comment: I would consider packing all booleans in a single byte/int/long and using: return bvals & (val ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0);